# Create variables within a loop with values in a dict and add'em to a list without the quotes

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, variables

I want to create a list of variables with values within a dict, till now I achieve this task but now I want to save the variables in a list to keep track of them for future operations, but when I save them. they appear as a strings.

This is the dict

```
js = {
'numbers' : ['one',
'two']
}
```

This is my code to create a variable with the values of the dict

```
for k, dk in js.items():
        for x in dk:
             globals()[x] = 'jojo' + str(x)
```

and this is the code that I've trying to create a list of the variables created

```
for k, dk in js.items():
    var_list = []
    for x in dk:
        var_list.append(globals()[x] = 'jojo' + str(x))
```

It gives me this error.

```
File "<ipython-input-286-ab2db6b5d08d>", line 4
    var_list.append(globals()[x] = 'jojo' + str(x))
                   ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: Probably not an ideal way. `var_list.append(globals()[x])`.

Comment: Why do you want to have these values in separate variables? Why don't you just want to go with a nice dict?

Answer (score 1):

When calling `.append()` on a list, the value passed in must be a value, not an expression.

```
# INVALID
var_list.append(globals()[x] = 'jojo' + str(x))

# VALID
globals()[x] = 'jojo' + str(x)
var_list.append(globals()[x])
```